# Apache Spark Efficient keys or values for large lookup table using 'distinct' and 'collect'

Tags: apache-spark, distinct, rdd

There is a large RDD map and I need to broadcast unique keys with index number using `zipWithIndex`

```
val lookupKyes = lookupRaw.keys.distinct().collect()
val lookupTable = lookupKyes.zipWithIndex
val bcLookUp = sc.broadcast(lookupTable)
```

A problem is distinct and collect, actually collect() does take a long time. 
So, my question is

1. `lookupRaw` has duplicates keys in each partition.distinct() takes unique keys first then the unique keys in each partition are collected in driver?
2. Is there more efficient way to collect unique values (or keys)? or a way to optimize this operation? I tried changing # of partitions using `coalesce` or `partionBy(new HashPartioner(n))`, but it doesn't work.

Please, share your experience. Thanks

Comment: `collect()` function gathers the content of a a distributed RDD into a single spark client (single node). Doing this you lose all benefits of distributed processing. See if it is possible to avoid the use of `collect()`

Comment: You're right. Collecting a big data needs avoiding.  But, as of now, each node has to refer to one large lookup table, bcLookUp, and that's why. So, I'm trying to find workaround if there is. Also, I'd like to know how distinct works in RDD exactly.

Comment: Can you try `val lookupTable = lookupRaw.keys.distinct().zipWithIndex()` to see if the performance increases